# Pulling a certain value from a JSON string in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have set up a bot for Discord that is taking every users' messages and using a sentiment classifier to determine if a message is positive or negative. See the POST request to the `text-processing.com` API below.

Given a message `'I am extremely happy'`, the API will return a response which is a string resembling JSON:

```
{"probability": {"neg": 0.32404484915164478, "neutral": 0.021768879244280313, "pos": 0.67595515084835522}, "label": "pos"}
```

How can I convert this JSON object to a str, so that I can easily interact with its data?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(repr(message.content), file=f)
        response = requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', {
            'text': message.content
        }).json()
        print(response, file=f)
        d = json.loads(response)
        print(d["probability"]["pos"], file=f)
        f.close()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The error code I am receiving is...

```
File "/Users/enzoromano/PycharmProjects/NewDiscordBot/NewBot.py", line 44, in on_message
    d = json.loads(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

Comment: `s['probability']['pos']` assuming your dictionary above is assigned to `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), you can achieve what you ask for by simply parsing the result directly as `json` instead that as `text`:

```
response = requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', {
    'text': message.content
}).json()
```

Comment: You are retrieving the data using [requests post](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/), which returns a [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). If such response is expected to be a json, you can call its method [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.json) to convert it to a dictionary directly.

Comment: @EnzoRomano Yes, instead of using `r.text`, use `r.json()` to automatically parse the JSON into a Python dictionary.

Comment: Okay so your answer works but I need to save my data as a str because when I used your code I got.... TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Comment: Could you provide the full exception and the row of code that rise such Exception?

Comment: You already convert the response to json with my answer code. If you try to convert it yet again to json it will surely fail.

Comment: So where exactly did I convert it a second time? Sorry I am confused thank you for sticking with me

Comment: When you run the `.json()` method you convert the response to json. When you run again `d = json.loads(response)` you are trying to convert a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: I would also suggest you to avoid editing the question in such a way, because it changes the original topic of the question. When you get a second issue after resolving the first one, you should accept the correct answer and eventually, if unable to solve the problem otherwise, ask another question.

Comment: Thank you very much luca, you were absolutely right.

Comment: Okay and thank you I will keep that in mind next time I edit a question, youre great help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `{"probability": {"neg": 0.32404484915164478, "neutral": 0.021768879244280313, "pos": 0.67595515084835522}, "label": "pos"}` really is a string, you can call `json.loads` on it, and access its values like you would any ordinary dict.

```
>>> s = """{"probability": {"neg": 0.32404484915164478, "neutral": 0.021768879244280313, "pos": 0.67595515084835522}, "label": "pos"}"""
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d["probability"]["pos"]
0.6759551508483552
```

Comment: Ah so I was wrong, I got the error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response'. Do you know how to change that "response" into a string?

Comment: You are handling a requests response object. Check out my answer to convert it directly into a dictionary, using requests own parser.

Comment: So every message will have a different rating though? For variable s, the text will always be different... In your answer you have written code for only one situation?